# Selecting DbContext based on Entity with AutoFac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac

I'm trying to specify which dbcontext to use based on entity with autofac. Below are my codes:

Global.asax

```
foreach (var database in DatabaseManager.Databases)
            {
                builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new CodesObjectContext(database.ConnectionString, database.Alias)) //database.Alias is database name
                    .As<IDbContext>()
                    .Named<IDbContext>(database.Alias)
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            }
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Is there anyway i can specify which dbcontext to pass to EfRepository?

```
public partial class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly IDbContext _context;
        private IDbSet<T> _entities;

        public EfRepository(IDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }
}
```

and in my entity i would have something like this

```
[DatabaseName("Database1")]
public partial class SampleEntity : BaseEntity
{
}
```

**UPDATED**
Here is my objectcontext class

```
public class CodesObjectContext : DbContext, IDbContext
    {
        public virtual string DatabaseName { get; private set; }
        public CodesObjectContext(string nameOrConnectionString, string databaseName)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            DatabaseName = databaseName;
        }            
}
```

So is there a way to match entity database attribute and context database name, then only pass this context to the repository constructor

Comment: HI Mantas, my question has nothing to do with JSON

Comment: maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes) is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi Munzer, nope. i want to use the custom attribute to specify which database to use for the context in repository

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have defined your attribute DatabaseName, I will answer

```
//first in your base context, define contructor that takes string as database name.
//It should be something like this 
public MyContext(string mydbName = "DefaultDBName") : base(mydbName)
        {
        }

// In your getter, do something like this, get database Name from your attributes  
string dbName =
            (DatabaseName) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof (DatabaseName));
if(dbName==null) throw new Exception ("Missing Attribute");
else
{
// .Name might change depending on your attribute
string DatabaseName = db.Name;
// then init your context 
    using (var db = new MyContext(DatabaseName))
    {//do something }
}
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: I have updated the question. I think you missed out autofac in the scope

Comment: I am not sure what is autofac, after reading the update, I still think that the answer need no change, except if you didn't create your DatabaseName annotation yet.